# Resolving urls from Route Values on server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am trying to create a ValidationAttribute *(for Remote validation which only works on the server side)* and inside the IsValid method, I need to resolve the url from url route values. Here is my initial set up :

```
public class ServerSideRemoteAttribute : ValidationAttribute {

    public string Controller { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public object RouteValues { get; set; }

    public ServerSideRemoteAttribute(string controller, string action) {

        this.Controller = controller;
        this.Action = action;
    }

    public ServerSideRemoteAttribute(string controller, string action, object routeValues) {

        this.Controller = controller;
        this.Action = action;
        this.RouteValues = routeValues;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext) {

        //Here I need to resolve the url in order to make a call to that controller action and get the JSON result back

        return base.IsValid(value, validationContext);
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(httpContext, new RouteData()));
var url = urlHelper.Action(Action, Controller, RouteValues);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It helped a lot. Would that resolve the full URL (like : localhost:6738/Home/Index/100)?

Comment: @tugberk, no it will not resolve to a full url. If you want an absolute url you will have to use the appropriate overload: `var url = urlHelper.Action(Action, Controller, RouteValues, urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme);`

Comment: Thanks again. I should have looked at the MSDN instead of being lazy :s